# Is it possible to group make this with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method which returns an `IList<IGrouping<bool, int>>`, I was wondering if it was possible to do this using LINQ.(Test case beneath I wrote to see what should happen, small numbers (<=100) should have a 'yes' boolean and big numbers (>100) should have a 'no' boolean.

```
public IList<IGrouping<bool, int>> GroupSmallAndBigNumbers(int[] numbers)
        {

        }
```

```
[Test]
        public void NumbersSmallerThanOrEqualTo100AndBiggerNumbersCanBeGroupedUsingGroupBy()
        {
            //Arrange
            int[] numbers = { 5, 700, 15, 108, 25, 28, 100 };
            int[] expectedSmallNumbers = { 5, 15, 25, 28, 100};
            int[] expectedBigNumbers = { 700, 108 };

            //Act
            var results = _examples.GroupSmallAndBigNumbers(numbers);

            //Assert
            Assert.That(results.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
            var smallNumbers = results[0];
            Assert.That(smallNumbers, Is.EquivalentTo(expectedSmallNumbers));
            var bigNumbers = results[1];
            Assert.That(bigNumbers, Is.EquivalentTo(expectedBigNumbers));
        }
```

Comment: /\ That being said, inside of GroupSmallAndBigNumbers, you can just do a simple loop over `numbers` to check the size.

Answer (score 3):

You could group by checking if each number is greater than 100.

```
public IList<IGrouping<bool, int>> GroupSmallAndBigNumbers(int[] numbers)
 => numbers.GroupBy(x => x >= 100).ToList();
```

Comment: How would you add the boolean to it then? for example 
```[(1, true), (2, true), (5,true), (1000000, false)]``` is what it could contain

Comment: Wouldn't you rather just look at the group key to get the boolean so that you only have one copy of it rather than one for each number? Sort of like: [(true, [1,2,5]), (false, [101,103])]?  That is how it is from the above.

Comment: @Trietch What do you mean by *"add the Boolean to it"*? The group `Key` is a `bool` (and it would cause a compile error if it didn't return the specified type, which is the type you defined in your question). Did you try the sample code and run into a problem?

Comment: @Trietch if it returned that list of (int, bool) pairs then your test wouldn’t pass.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) would work better (and easier) for you. Using that, you can easily do something like this:

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 700, 15, 108, 25, 28, 100 };
Dictionary<int, bool> dict = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    if (number > 100)
        dict.Add(number, true);
    else
       dict.Add(number, false);
}
```

Comment: This solution imposes the restriction that the numbers are unique.